# Troubleshooting non-functional starter after collision

Tags: ford, starting, starter, explorer

My 2002 Ford Explorer was in a front end collision.  The engine was not damaged. It did push my radiator up against the fan while we were still on the scene. I freed the fan, hit the fuel reset and the truck started up. I shut it off got it towed home and now all my accessories work but the starter will not even crank. The starter is brand new.

Does anyone have any suggestions regarding what the issue might be?

Comment: Do you hear the starter tick when you turn the key to "start" or just nothing?

Comment: Like @kyle_engineer says, please provide more details about the starting process. It can be as simple as damaged wiring or as complex as a bad starting system component.